# how I Create a calculated column in SharePoint and writing formula using lookup columns, other

Tags: calculated-column

how I Create a calculated column in SharePoint and writing formula using lookup columns, other.

I want to create a calculated column that the field in the formula I use lookup column

plz, help me!

Comment: how i can use workflow nintex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Lookup columns` cannot be referenced in a `calculated column` formula.

Check [The Supported and Unsupported Columns in SharePoint Calculated Column Formula.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

**The suggested workaround**

- To use a workflow/event receiver that copies the lookup column value into an another column with a text data type.
- Then use that copied field in your formula.

Check the detail steps at [How to use Lookup field in SharePoint Calculated Column Formula.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/lookup-field-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)